# Is there a way for PHP to check if there is a number behind the

Tags: php

Is there a way for PHP to check if there is an number after the . in a variable?
for example: `$x=4.5` and now i want PHP to check if its a round number or one with a number after the . like shown in `$x`. I made a script where i want PHP to devide my Variale by 2 and then check if the variable is now round or has a decimal space.

```
while($dezimal !== 0) {
        $dezimal/2;
        //here is where i need to check if $dezimal is round or not
        floor($dezimal);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [modulo operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) will tell you if a number is evenly divisible by another.

```
if ($dezimal % 2 === 0) {
    // number divides evenly
} else {
    // number has a remainder
}
```